# Google Sign In JS Library - Google Sign in Button Doesn't load for some users

Tags: javascript, python, google-signin

Summary:
We are using the https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client Client to render a Login With Google Button on our user interface.

The problem is that the sign-in button doesn't render for some users and this is really frustrating as we see no error for this case.

this is our login page: https://bigcashweb.com/signin

Here are some hotjar user session recordings for the same:

https://insights.hotjar.com/r?site=3558427&recording=33683989370&token=0a5bcbd2d89af66f6e9530fc485c393c

https://insights.hotjar.com/r?site=3558427&recording=33693296677&token=4153b307613209713d9f4eb8de70cd91

It would mean the world to me if someone could help me with this. I have been trying to figure this out for weeks and reached nowhere.

We are using as documented here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview